# UISplitViewController with MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, ipad, monotouch.dialog, uitabcontroller

Using a UISplitViewController with MonoTouch.Dialog (DialogViewController) I am having issues when using the "back" button of the navigation controller:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeykT.png

There is a big animation on the detail side vertically from top to bottom.

I uploaded a small MonoTouch sample to https://github.com/t9mike/MonoTouch-TabPlusNav1-Sample. [Since updated with fix]

I am using the excellent MonoTouch.Dialog library, also on GitHub. The example references this.

How I am creating the view controller for the first tab:

```
var spit_view = new MySplitViewController();
spit_view.Delegate = new UISplitViewControllerDelegate();
spit_view.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] { 
    new MyNavigationController(), 
    new DetailViewController("Tab #1") 
};
Add(UITabBarSystemItem.Search, spit_view); // custom method
```

Is there a fix for the vertical animation when I pop navigation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you first question:

> Is there a fix for the vertical animation when I pop navigation?

Look at:
[UINavigationController scrolls down on back button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743028/uinavigationcontroller-scrolls-down-on-back-button-click)

Note that you have a better chance to get answers (and faster ones) if you split your questions :-)